# nginx memcached

Tags: nginx, memcached

I try to use nginx with memcached with this configuration:

```
server {

    ...

    location / {
    default_type            text/html;
    set $memcached_key      $uri;
        memcached_pass 127.0.0.1:11211;
        error_page     404 = @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/tmp/site.sock;
    }

}
```

But all requests go to uwsgi with no memcache use:

> nginx -V
>
> nginx -V nginx version: nginx/1.1.19 TLS SNI support enabled configure
>   arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
>   --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
>   --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module

There is no ngx_http_memcached_module in output.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and nginx installed with `apt-get install nginx`.

Does that mean I must install it to use memcached or something else?

Comment: Hi, how did you install that module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html#memcached_pass

```
The ngx_http_memcached_module module allows to obtain responses from a memcached 
server. The key is set in the $memcached_key variable. A response should be put 
in memcached in advance via means that are external to nginx.
```

in other words, nginx can only retrieve things already stored in memcache

the `means that are external to nginx` should most likely be your uwsgi app

Comment: Thanx, it clarifies.. but is it possible to populate memcached by nginx without do it on backend, nginx recieve result so why it can't save it in memcached?

Comment: not sure why that's the case, cause nobody has bothered to implement it sofar I guess

Comment: there's a 3th party module that does support set, see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMemcModule (note 3th party module means you'll have to compile nginx yourself)

Comment: @cobaco I get the ngx_http_memcached_module included when installing nginx from apt-get when on Ubuntu 12.04 but not on 14.04. Edit: Its not listed in the `configure arguments` on either installation though. Weird.